# How to select unique values in d3.js from data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am using the following code to populate my Combobox using d3.js

```
d3.csv("Results_New.txt", function(data) {
dataset=data;
d3.select("#road").selectAll("option")
.data(data).enter().append("option").text(function(d){return d.roadname;}).attr("value",function(d){return d.roadname;});
});
```

There are different rows with the same name. The combobox is populating with these duplicate names. For example in multiple rows the name of the road is I-80.But in the combobox I want to see I-80 only once. How can I do that?

Comment: Filter the duplicates from the data before passing it to D3.

Comment: How can I do that. I am reading the CSV file and using the data read from csv file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Filter your data retaining unique keys only by `d3.map`

```
d3.select("#road").selectAll("option")
    .data(d3.map(data, function(d){return d.roadname;}).keys())
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .text(function(d){return d;})
    .attr("value",function(d){return d;});
```

Comment: d3.map(data, function(d){return d.roadname;}) is nopt working. No values are now seen in the combobox

Comment: Do I need to do further preprocessing before using d3.map(data, function(d){return d.roadname;})

Comment: I edited my code as above. After mapping the data using `d3.map`, an array of objects indexed by `roadname` is returned. Extracting the `keys()` will give you a *clean* list roadnames.

Comment: I have some problems with your code? Some roads are not being shown in the combox. For example its showing I-74 but not showing I-74 Illinois

Answer (score 7):

`d3.map` is deprecated - the d3 devs now recommend simply using JavaScript's built-in `Array.map`. (In fact the entire `d3-collection` module is now [deprecated](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection), with similar rationale for `d3.set`.)

Here's a concise and (I think) elegant way to do this in ES6, using `Array.map`, `Set`, and the spread operator `...`:

```
let options = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.roadname))]; 
// optionally add .sort() to the end of that line to sort the unique values
// alphabetically rather than by insertion order

d3.select('#road')
  .selectAll('option')
    .data(options)
  .enter()
    .append('option')
    .text(d => d)
    .attr('value', d => d);
```