# D3 to return unique values to menu combobox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, combobox

I have this data in a csv:

```
Category,country
XXX,uk
XXX,usa
XXX,usa
XXX,usa
XXX,mex
XXX,ireland
ZZZ,uk
ZZZ,uk
ZZZ,uk
ZZZ,usa
ZZZ,aruba
ZZZ,ireland
YYY,foo
YYY,foo
```

My code then creates three category radio button for XXX, YYY and ZZZ.
When the user clicks a radio the menu combobox should reflect the unique countries associated with that category.

A (not!) working example of where I'm up to: http://plnkr.co/edit/6zVkTJvTT3ZXrnELPRnx?p=preview

Current code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>comboBoxWithRadios</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

    #projection-menu {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        top: 45px;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="radioDiv">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="dataset" id="dataset" value="XXX"> XXX</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="dataset" id="dataset" value="YYY" checked> YYY</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="dataset" id="dataset" value="ZZZ">ZZZ</label>
    </div>
    <select id="projection-menu"></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    d3.select("input[value=\"YYY\"]").property("checked", true);
    var exampleCSV = "comboBoxWithRadios.csv"


    selectDataset();

    d3.selectAll("input")
        .on("change", selectDataset);

    function selectDataset() {

        var v = this.value;
        if (undefined == v) {
            v = "YYY"
        }

        d3.csv(exampleCSV, function(rows) {
            dta = rows.filter(function(row) {
                if (row['Category'] == v) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            //clear out the combobox
            removeOptions(document.getElementById("projection-menu"));

            var menu = d3.select("#projection-menu")
                .on("change", change);

            menu.selectAll("option")
                .data(dta)
                .enter()
                .append("option")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.country;
                });
        });
    };


    function removeOptions(selectbox) {
        var i;
        for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            selectbox.remove(i);
        }
    }

    function change() {
        console.log(this.value);
    };


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer [How to select unique values in d3.js from data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572015/how-to-select-unique-values-in-d3-js-from-data) and this modified plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/DtbYRtMb11vhDn2PTecN?p=preview.

In short, with the use of

```
d3.map(dta, function(d){return d.country;}).keys()
```

you get unique countries. I've also modified the text like this:

```
.text(function(d) {
                    return d;
                });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the answer and demo - it works exactly as I wanted - I had spotted that previous post but as new to js had trouble implementing it. Still a bit mysterious to me as `keys()` to me infers key-value pairs but intuitively I would have had country as the value not the key?

Comment: Glad it helped! Take a look at the documentation of [map](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#maps). The signature of map is `d3.map([object[, key]]) ` so with your example, `d3.map(dta, function(d){return d.country;})` map creates a dictionary with d.country as keys as returned by the function passed as the second parameter to map, and {Category:country} as values (the key-value pair of the current item in dta). Then `.keys()` returns the unique by definition keys of the dictionary as a list.